# PHP form to csv file but showing only commas

Tags: php, file, csv, export-to-csv

This is the first time needing to export out form data into a file as a csv file in a specific folder. The form is functioning and exporting out a csv but the export csv file only shows commas and no information. Any thoughts on how to fix this? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/includes-new/common.php");

$GLOBALS["bodyID"] = "layout21";
$GLOBALS["layout"] = " layout21";

$GLOBALS["pageTitle"] = "info";
$GLOBALS["tab"] = "info";
$GLOBALS["section"] = "info";
$GLOBALS["page"] = "default";

$query = strip_tags($_GET["query"]);
$form  = "document.contact.";
$focus = ".focus();";



if($query != null){

    if(is_numeric($query)){
        $zip = strtoupper(substr(trim($query), 0, 5));
    } else {
        $pieces = explode(",", $query);
        $city = ucwords(trim($pieces[0]));
        $state = strtoupper(substr(trim($pieces[1]), 0, 2));
    }

} else {

    $city = ucwords(strip_tags($_GET["city"]));
    $state = strtoupper(substr(strip_tags($_GET["state"]), 0, 2));
    $zip = strtoupper(substr(strip_tags($_GET["zip"]), 0, 5));

}


if($_POST["Submit"]){

    $fname = $_POST["fname"];                       //required
    $lname = $_POST["lname"];                       //required
    $email = strtolower($_POST["email"]);           //required
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];                       //required
    $preferredContact = $_POST["preferredContact"]; //required
    $signature = $_POST["signature"];                       //required



    if(!$fname){
        $errorField = "fname";
        $requiredFields[] = $errorField;
        $errorMessage[] = "Please enter your first name";
        $errorOnload[] = $form . $errorField . $focus;
    }

    if(!$lname){
        $errorField = "lname";
        $requiredFields[] = $errorField;
        $errorMessage[] = "Please enter your last name";
        $errorOnload[] = $form . $errorField . $focus;
    }

    if(!$email){
        $errorField = "email";
        $requiredFields[] = $errorField;
        $errorMessage[] = "Please enter your email address";
        $errorOnload[] = $form . $errorField . $focus;
    } else {
        if(!validate_email($email)){
            $errorField = "email";
            $requiredFields[] = $errorField;
            $errorMessage[] = "Please enter a valid email address";
            $errorOnload[] = $form . $errorField . $focus;
        }
    }

    if(!$phone){
        $errorField = "phone";
        $requiredFields[] = $errorField;
        $errorMessage[] = "Please enter your phone number";
        $errorOnload[] = $form . $errorField . $focus;
    } else {
        if(strlen($phone) < 10){
            $errorField = "phone";
            $requiredFields[] = $errorField;
            $errorMessage[] = "Please enter a valid phone number with area code";
            $errorOnload[] = $form . $errorField . $focus;
        }
    }

    if($preferredContact == "null"){
        $errorField = "preferredContact";
        $requiredFields[] = $errorField;
        $errorMessage[] = "Please select your preferred contact method";
        $errorOnload[] = $form . $errorField . $focus;
    }

    if(!$signature){
        $errorField = "signature";
        $requiredFields[] = $errorField;
        $errorMessage[] = "Please enter your full name";
        $errorOnload[] = $form . $errorField . $focus;
    }

    if ($errorField == null) {

        if (isCaptchaValid() == false) {
            // the security code was incorrect
            $errorField = CAPTCHA_ID;
            $requiredFields[] = $errorField;
            $errorMessage[] = "Please enter a valid security code";
            $errorOnload[] = $form . $errorField . $focus;
        }

    }

    if($errorField == null){

        $to_name = "email@me.com";
        $to_email = "email@me.com";
        $subject = "some subject";

        $interestedProducts = "";
        while(list($key,$val) = @each($products)){
            $interestedProducts .= "$val, ";
        }

        if($interestedProducts != null){
            $interestedProducts = substr($interestedProducts, 0, -2);
        }

        $message = "";
        $message .= "some message sent\n\n";
        // $message .= "Current Customer:  $customer\n";
        $message .= "First Name:  $fname\n";
        $message .= "Last Name:  $lname\n";
        $message .= "Email Address:  $email\n";
        $message .= "Phone:  $phone\n";
        $message .= "Preferred Contact Method:  $preferredContact\n";
                //$message .= "\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nThis message was submitted through the website";

        send_email($to_name, $to_email, "$fname $lname", $email, "Website -  " . $subject, $message, $today, "false", "false");


        $fname = "";
        $lname = "";
        $email = "";
        $phone = "";
        $preferredContact = "";
        $signature = "";


        // Unique "Thank you" page.
        header("Location: thanks.php");
        exit;
    }

} else {
    $errorOnload[] = $form . "customer" . $focus;
}

if($GLOBALS["focusRequiredField"]){
    $GLOBALS["onload"] = $errorOnload[0];

}

getTemplateHeader();
getTemplateColumn("1", "start");
getTemplateSidebar("default");

?>

<h1>
    <?php echo $GLOBALS["pageTitle"]; ?>
</h1>

<? echo displayErrorMsg($errorMessage); ?>
<? echo displaySuccessMsg($successMessage); ?>

<p>
    body copy</p>

<p><strong>copy</strong></p>

<p>You have selected the <strong><?php echo getVisitorCity(); ?></strong> location.</p>

<div class="form-container">
    <form action="<? echo $GLOBALS["self"]; ?>" name="contact"
        method="post">
        <fieldset>

            <h4 style="margin-top: 15px;">Contact Information</h4>

            <div>
                <label for="fname"
                <? checkRequiredField("fname", $requiredFields); ?>>First Name: <em>*</em>
                </label> <input id="fname" type="text" name="fname"
                    value="<? echo $fname; ?>" size="30" maxlength="75"
                    <? checkRequiredField("fname", $requiredFields); ?> />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="lname"
                <? checkRequiredField("lname", $requiredFields); ?>>Last Name: <em>*</em>
                </label> <input id="lname" type="text" name="lname"
                    value="<? echo $lname; ?>" size="30" maxlength="75"
                    <? checkRequiredField("lname", $requiredFields); ?> />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="email"
                <? checkRequiredField("email", $requiredFields); ?>>Email Address:
                    <em>*</em>
                </label> <input id="email" type="text" name="email"
                    value="<? echo $email; ?>" size="30" maxlength="75"
                    <? checkRequiredField("email", $requiredFields); ?> />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="phone"
                <? checkRequiredField("phone", $requiredFields); ?>>Phone Number: <em>*</em>
                </label> <input id="phone" type="text" name="phone"
                    value="<? echo $phone; ?>" size="20" maxlength="20"
                    <? checkRequiredField("phone", $requiredFields); ?> />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="preferredContact"
                <? checkRequiredField("preferredContact", $requiredFields); ?>>Preferred
                    Contact: <em>*</em>
                </label> <select name="preferredContact" id="preferredContact"
                <? checkRequiredField("preferredContact", $requiredFields); ?>>
                    <option value="null"
                    <? if($preferredContact == "null"){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>[Select
                        Contact Method]</option>
                    <option value="Email"
                    <? if($preferredContact == "Email"){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>Email</option>
                    <option value="Phone"
                    <? if($preferredContact == "Phone"){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>Phone</option>
                </select>
            </div>


            <h4 style="margin-top: 15px;">Sign here using electronic signature</h4>

            <div>
                <label for="signature"
                <? checkRequiredField("signature", $requiredFields); ?>>Full Name: <em>*</em>
                </label> <input id="signature" type="text" name="signature" alt="i.e. Jane Marie Doe"
                    value="<? echo $signature; ?>" size="50" maxlength="75"
                    <? checkRequiredField("signature", $requiredFields); ?> />
            </div>




            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <?php echo displayCaptcha($requiredFields); ?>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>

            <div>
                <label class="nopointer">&nbsp;</label> <input type="submit"
                    name="Submit" value="Submit Inquiry"
                    onclick="this.value='<? echo $GLOBALS["processing_text"]; ?>';" />
            </div>

        <?php   if(count($errorMessage) > 0)
{
    $numErrors = count($errorMessage); 
    echo("<p>There was " . $numErrors . "an error:</p>\n");
    echo("<ul>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
}
else
{
    $fs = fopen("/tmp/mydata.csv","a");
    fwrite($fs,$varfname . ", " . $varlname . ", " . $varemail . ", " . $varphone . ", " . $varpreferredContact . ", " . $varsignature ."\n");
    fclose($fs);

    exit;
}
?>


            <? echo buildRequiredMessage(); ?>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

<?php
$GLOBALS["disclosures"][] = array("", "");
getTemplateColumn("1", "end");

getTemplateNavigation($GLOBALS["tab"]);
getTemplateFooter();
?>
```

Comment: if you're going to ask about generating csv, do you really think it's necessary to show 10 miles of html and validation code? And if you want to output data to a csv file, don't you think you should use variables that are actually defined? search your code for `$varlname` and see how many times (and where) it shows up...

Comment: pleas follow this advise:http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve most of the code posted is eronous

Comment: Because (*most probable cause*), all your variables in your `fwrite()` function are incorrect. For example, you have `$varfname` yet you're probably trying to fetch it from `$fname = $_POST["fname"];` etc.

Comment: or just turn register globals on (giggle)

Comment: Change it to `fwrite($fs,$fname . ", " . $lname . ", " . $email . ", " . $phone . ", " . $preferredContact . ", " . $signature ."\n");` and it should kick like a mule. I'd make it as answer but I'm not having worms as a late night snack. But, you say the word, and I'm in like Flynn.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm next to certain it's going to work. @user3123395

Comment: Keep me posted, curious to know. @user3123395

Comment: Just tried it and it didn't work, still showing commas.

Comment: Give me a few minutes. I'll try and test your whole code. @user3123395

Comment: Ok, it took me a while but here's what worked for me. I placed what I wrote in my answer under the `mail()` function, then I commented out all the `$fname = ""; $lname = ""; $email = ""; $phone = ""; $preferredContact = ""; $signature = "";` @user3123395 There were a lot of functions that I did not have access to, which are most likely in a seperate file that you have, but I did manage on my own to comment those functions out.

Comment: See my **EDIT** --- tested (to a certain extent) and working. @user3123395

Answer (score 0):

Because (*and the most probable cause*), all your variables in your `fwrite()` function are incorrect.

For example, you have `$varfname` yet it seems related to `$fname = $_POST["fname"];` etc.

Change it to:

```
fwrite($fs,$fname . ", " . $lname . ", " . $email . ", " . $phone . ", " . $preferredContact . ", " . $signature ."\n");
```

---

### EDIT (tested)

Some parts have been commented out with `/*...*/` in order to keep their original placements, and have been located elsewhere.

The `fwrite()` function has been copied under the `mail()` function and others commented out.

The following worked for me, including part of my original answer.

```
<?php
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/includes-new/common.php");

$GLOBALS["bodyID"] = "layout21";
$GLOBALS["layout"] = " layout21";

$GLOBALS["pageTitle"] = "info";
$GLOBALS["tab"] = "info";
$GLOBALS["section"] = "info";
$GLOBALS["page"] = "default";

$query = strip_tags($_GET["query"]);
$form  = "document.contact.";
$focus = ".focus();";

if($query != null){

    if(is_numeric($query)){
        $zip = strtoupper(substr(trim($query), 0, 5));
    } else {
        $pieces = explode(",", $query);
        $city = ucwords(trim($pieces[0]));
        $state = strtoupper(substr(trim($pieces[1]), 0, 2));
    }

} else {

    $city = ucwords(strip_tags($_GET["city"]));
    $state = strtoupper(substr(strip_tags($_GET["state"]), 0, 2));
    $zip = strtoupper(substr(strip_tags($_GET["zip"]), 0, 5));

}


if($_POST["Submit"]){

    $fname = $_POST["fname"];                       //required
    $lname = $_POST["lname"];                       //required
    $email = strtolower($_POST["email"]);           //required
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];                       //required
    $preferredContact = $_POST["preferredContact"]; //required
    $signature = $_POST["signature"];                       //required

    if(!$fname){
        $errorField = "fname";
        $requiredFields[] = $errorField;
        $errorMessage[] = "Please enter your first name";
        $errorOnload[] = $form . $errorField . $focus;
    }

    if(!$lname){
        $errorField = "lname";
        $requiredFields[] = $errorField;
        $errorMessage[] = "Please enter your last name";
        $errorOnload[] = $form . $errorField . $focus;
    }

    if(!$email){
        $errorField = "email";
        $requiredFields[] = $errorField;
        $errorMessage[] = "Please enter your email address";
        $errorOnload[] = $form . $errorField . $focus;
    } else {
        if(!validate_email($email)){
            $errorField = "email";
            $requiredFields[] = $errorField;
            $errorMessage[] = "Please enter a valid email address";
            $errorOnload[] = $form . $errorField . $focus;
        }
    }

    if(!$phone){
        $errorField = "phone";
        $requiredFields[] = $errorField;
        $errorMessage[] = "Please enter your phone number";
        $errorOnload[] = $form . $errorField . $focus;
    } else {
        if(strlen($phone) < 10){
            $errorField = "phone";
            $requiredFields[] = $errorField;
            $errorMessage[] = "Please enter a valid phone number with area code";
            $errorOnload[] = $form . $errorField . $focus;
        }
    }

    if($preferredContact == "null"){
        $errorField = "preferredContact";
        $requiredFields[] = $errorField;
        $errorMessage[] = "Please select your preferred contact method";
        $errorOnload[] = $form . $errorField . $focus;
    }

    if(!$signature){
        $errorField = "signature";
        $requiredFields[] = $errorField;
        $errorMessage[] = "Please enter your full name";
        $errorOnload[] = $form . $errorField . $focus;
    }

    if ($errorField == null) {

        if (isCaptchaValid() == false) {
            // the security code was incorrect
            $errorField = CAPTCHA_ID;
            $requiredFields[] = $errorField;
            $errorMessage[] = "Please enter a valid security code";
            $errorOnload[] = $form . $errorField . $focus;
        }

    }

    if($errorField == null){

        $to_name = "email@me.com";
        $to_email = "email@me.com";
        $subject = "some subject";

        $interestedProducts = "";
        while(list($key,$val) = @each($products)){
            $interestedProducts .= "$val, ";
        }

        if($interestedProducts != null){
            $interestedProducts = substr($interestedProducts, 0, -2);
        }

        $message = "";
        $message .= "some message sent\n\n";
        // $message .= "Current Customer:  $customer\n";
        $message .= "First Name:  $fname\n";
        $message .= "Last Name:  $lname\n";
        $message .= "Email Address:  $email\n";
        $message .= "Phone:  $phone\n";
        $message .= "Preferred Contact Method:  $preferredContact\n";
                //$message .= "\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nThis message was submitted through the website";

        send_email($to_name, $to_email, "$fname $lname", $email, "Website -  " . $subject, $message, $today, "false", "false");
        
        $fs = fopen("/tmp/mydata.csv","a");
        fwrite($fs,$varfname . ", " . $varlname . ", " . $varemail . ", " . $varphone . ", " . $varpreferredContact . ", " . $varsignature ."\n");
        fclose($fs);

    // exit;

/*
        $fname = "";
        $lname = "";
        $email = "";
        $phone = "";
        $preferredContact = "";
        $signature = "";
*/

        // Unique "Thank you" page.
        header("Location: thanks.php");
        exit;
    }

} else {
    $errorOnload[] = $form . "customer" . $focus;
}

if($GLOBALS["focusRequiredField"]){
    $GLOBALS["onload"] = $errorOnload[0];

}

getTemplateHeader();
getTemplateColumn("1", "start");
getTemplateSidebar("default");

?>

<h1>
    <?php echo $GLOBALS["pageTitle"]; ?>
</h1>

<? echo displayErrorMsg($errorMessage); ?>
<? echo displaySuccessMsg($successMessage); ?>

<p>
    body copy</p>

<p><strong>copy</strong></p>

<p>You have selected the <strong><?php echo getVisitorCity(); ?></strong> location.</p>

<div class="form-container">
    <form action="<? echo $GLOBALS["self"]; ?>" name="contact"
        method="post">
        <fieldset>

            <h4 style="margin-top: 15px;">Contact Information</h4>

            <div>
                <label for="fname"
                <? checkRequiredField("fname", $requiredFields); ?>>First Name: <em>*</em>
                </label> <input id="fname" type="text" name="fname"
                    value="<? echo $fname; ?>" size="30" maxlength="75"
                    <? checkRequiredField("fname", $requiredFields); ?> />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="lname"
                <? checkRequiredField("lname", $requiredFields); ?>>Last Name: <em>*</em>
                </label> <input id="lname" type="text" name="lname"
                    value="<? echo $lname; ?>" size="30" maxlength="75"
                    <? checkRequiredField("lname", $requiredFields); ?> />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="email"
                <? checkRequiredField("email", $requiredFields); ?>>Email Address:
                    <em>*</em>
                </label> <input id="email" type="text" name="email"
                    value="<? echo $email; ?>" size="30" maxlength="75"
                    <? checkRequiredField("email", $requiredFields); ?> />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="phone"
                <? checkRequiredField("phone", $requiredFields); ?>>Phone Number: <em>*</em>
                </label> <input id="phone" type="text" name="phone"
                    value="<? echo $phone; ?>" size="20" maxlength="20"
                    <? checkRequiredField("phone", $requiredFields); ?> />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="preferredContact"
                <? checkRequiredField("preferredContact", $requiredFields); ?>>Preferred
                    Contact: <em>*</em>
                </label> <select name="preferredContact" id="preferredContact"
                <? checkRequiredField("preferredContact", $requiredFields); ?>>
                    <option value="null"
                    <? if($preferredContact == "null"){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>[Select
                        Contact Method]</option>
                    <option value="Email"
                    <? if($preferredContact == "Email"){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>Email</option>
                    <option value="Phone"
                    <? if($preferredContact == "Phone"){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>Phone</option>
                </select>
            </div>


            <h4 style="margin-top: 15px;">Sign here using electronic signature</h4>

            <div>
                <label for="signature"
                <? checkRequiredField("signature", $requiredFields); ?>>Full Name: <em>*</em>
                </label> <input id="signature" type="text" name="signature" alt="i.e. Jane Marie Doe"
                    value="<? echo $signature; ?>" size="50" maxlength="75"
                    <? checkRequiredField("signature", $requiredFields); ?> />
            </div>




            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <?php echo displayCaptcha($requiredFields); ?>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>

            <div>
                <label class="nopointer">&nbsp;</label> <input type="submit"
                    name="Submit" value="Submit Inquiry"
                    onclick="this.value='<? echo $GLOBALS["processing_text"]; ?>';" />
            </div>

        <?php   if(count($errorMessage) > 0)
{
    $numErrors = count($errorMessage); 
    echo("<p>There was " . $numErrors . "an error:</p>\n");
    echo("<ul>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
}


/* original placement for fwrite() function commented out */

/*
else
{
    $fs = fopen("/tmp/mydata.csv","a");
    fwrite($fs,$varfname . ", " . $varlname . ", " . $varemail . ", " . $varphone . ", " . $varpreferredContact . ", " . $varsignature ."\n");
    fclose($fs);

    exit;
}
*/
?>


            <? echo buildRequiredMessage(); ?>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

<?php
$GLOBALS["disclosures"][] = array("", "");
getTemplateColumn("1", "end");

getTemplateNavigation($GLOBALS["tab"]);
getTemplateFooter();
?>
```